# User controls & Composite web server controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-server-controls

Which approach should I prefer when it comes to writing a custom control in ASP.Net. Should I create a custom user control or should I create a Composite Web Server control. And how about adding a designer support to the composite control. How are they different from each other and their pros and cons.

Difference with an example of each will be preferable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a comparison in the official documentation: [Composite Control vs. User Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719735.aspx)

I would go for a composite control if I plan to propose controls to other developers, like 3rd party controls vendors do. Then, I would add designer capabilities to these controls.

But, if I just want to develop controls that do custom things in a project, then user controls are easier to write, and require less ASP.NET inner knowledge.

*Side note*: Kothari's book is very good and a must read when developing composite controls, but it's not enough. Because it's an ASP.NET 1.1 book, there is no mention of very important notions that appeared in ASP.NET 2: the concepts of `DataBoundControl` vs `DataSourceControl`. All ASP.NET custom controls that appeared starting with .NET 2+, like FormView/GridView/DetailsView and ObjectDataSource, SqlDataSource, etc. are built on these fundamental concepts that are not covered in the book at all. Unfortunately, the book has never been updated, and I don't know of any other books that explain this with sufficient details.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need the following book

[Developing Microsoft Asp.Net Server Controls and Components by Nikhil Kothari](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735615829)

Comment: I second that, even though the book is old.

Comment: @Shekhar: no, the explanation will not do more good. Get the book.

Comment: If everyone on StackOverflow answered questions with "go read this book", this place would be useless.  If you really want to post something along these lines, consider at least answering the question to some degree and referring to the book for more detail.  The person who posted the question did not ask for your opinion on a good book on developing web controls.